# If I buy another disc copy of a game, will my saved files (saved to my Xbox Profile) still be there for the other disc?

Tags: xbox-one, physical-media

If I buy another disc copy of a game, will my saved files (which I have signed in through my Xbox profile) transfer all my data from my original disc to my newest disc?

Answer (score 2):

The disc shouldn't make a difference.

Your save data is stored either on the hard drive of your Xbox One or in the cloud (or both).  The disc is really only their to install the game and then to be used to prove that you own the game when running it.

Comment: I also _guess_ that the save files are associated with your profile. Changing the profile and playing the same game should have its own save files.